# Start activity from button.setOnClickListener which lies in my RecyclerView

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, start-activity

I want an activity/class to run on a `Button` click. The `Button` is inside my `RecyclerView`. I first had the code in my `MainActivity` with:

```
btnComplete.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, DelComplete::class.java))}
```

This code was in my `onCreate` of my `MainActivity`. How ever on running the code I found the error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

My first thought was that it could not reach the `Button` since it was in the `RecyclerView`. So I tried to put the code in my `RecyclerView`. But I read that it is not a good idea to put it in you `RecyclerView` and I dont know what to do with the `Context` as it keeps throwing errors.

`RecyclerView`:

```
     txtbutton1.setOnClickListener {
                    confirmdel()
                    modal.tvdone = "Delivered"
                    Log.e("Clicked", "Successful delivery")
                    //this is where I add code to export data through api
                    modal.state = DataState.Success
                    Status = 1
                    notifyDataSetChanged()}
```

```
    private fun confirmdel() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, DelComplete::class.java))}
```

It might be as simple as filling in the `Context` but I am unsure what the `Context` must be to test that theory.

Recyclerview- table_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWOrder"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:text="@string/worder"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDElNote"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:text="@string/delnote"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCompany"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:text="@string/company"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnComplete"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_header_cell_bg"
        android:drawableTint="#70D5C8"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnException"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttvdone"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:text="@string/weight"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The reason why I have a `Button` in my `RecyclerView` is on every entry a driver should be able to give feedback on a delivery. Every entry is a different order. Did I go the wrong way of doing this?

[image: My app]

My Button does the following:

```
   txtbutton1.setOnClickListener {

                    confirmdel()
                    modal.tvdone = "Delivered"
                    Log.e("Clicked", "Successful delivery")
                    //this is where I add code to export data through api
                    modal.state = DataState.Success
                    Status = 1
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
```

It does that with no problem. Now however I want to add an `AlertDialog` and update data in my `DB` with the `setOnClickListener`. Will this be possible from within my adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the context like this :

```
class Adapter(private val context: Context, private val myList: List<String>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>()
```

And pass the context where required like this

```
    private fun confirmdel() {
    startActivity(Intent(context, DelComplete::class.java))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put a button inside of your RecyclerView, unless you are referring to a button as the item itself.
RecyclerViews are used to render as much as items as you have in your data source, instead of hardcoding them, so I think you want to handle the click on a single item and navigate to another Activity with the data of that item.

You can do that by following [these](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interacting-with-items?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#0) steps. This is a codelab made by Google and explains how to handle the item click.

In addition, you should do [those](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-recyclerview-fundamentals?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#0) too, in order to better understanding.RecyclerViews

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I will upload my Recylerview quick.

Comment: I understand what you mean now with don't put a button inside RecyclerView. I am just trying to have something happen on the click of a button. I need context for this.

Comment: I see you updated your question. If you want a button to interact with, just define it in the item and handle it with code.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean with define it in item and handle it with code?
The main reason I wanted to start another activity is because I want to try and clean up my code. I have a habit of putting everything in one class.  Is it possible to start an activity from inside an adapter?

Comment: No its not. An "item" is what you put inside your recyclerview, and its printed multiple times.

Comment: My buttons are defined as items. They have code that they execute fine. Just not the code that I want to add now